# How do you model a damped spring falling (the whole system) under gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

You would think the equations of motion could be derived from:

$$F = -kx -cv -mg$$

Where $v$ is the velocity but then; the damping will also slowdown the fall which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

The damping does slow down the fall. Think of a feather falling down in air. Your equation looks correct.